# Push inside Tuple TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am learning TypeScript especially the `tuple` type. According to [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) this is the definition of `tuple` :

> A tuple type is another sort of Array type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions.

I tried this :

```js
let test : [string,number] ;
test = ['a',2];
console.log(test); // output ["a", 2]
```

Now when I try to assign an invalid value to the `test` variable :

```js
test = ['a',2,5] // Error : Type '[string, number, number]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.
```

However when I try tp push inside `test` the compiler does not complain

```js
test.push(5) // NO ERROS
console.log(test) // output ["a", 2, 5]
```

How this can be possible ?

Comment: _"According to w3schools..."_ -- don't get informed from random websites (w3schools in particular has a long history of teaching incorrect things), go directly to the source: [the official TypeScript documentation page about object types, section "Tuple Types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).

Comment: even in the official docs it's almost the same definitionbut you are right I will update it

Comment: I don't say that the official documentation answers your question. I just say to search the source of truth first. Usually the tutorials or articles about a language feature do not cover all the functionality and the answer might lay in plain sight in the documentation. Apparently it is not the case here :-( Using a readonly tuple, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75265047/4265352) suggests could be a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current design of TypeScript and has been reported at this GitHub issue:

[microsoft/TypeScript#52375 - Bug: incorrect tuple (array) type after changing in place](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52375)

The current development lead of TS [posted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52375#issuecomment-1400953701) this comment about it:

> **RyanCavanaugh**:
>
> The in-place mutation methods for arrays aren't supported from a control flow perspective. I recommend using `readonly [string, number]` in most scenarios.

and also [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48465#issuecomment-1081143116) this:

> **RyanCavanaugh**:
>
> `[X]` and `readonly [X]` seem to cover the use cases fairly well. I would probably suggest
>
> ```
> type StrictTuple<T> = Omit<T, "push" | "pop" | "shift" | "unshift" | "sort">;
> ```
>
> since things like `indexOf`, `map`, `every`, etc are still presumably useful.